# Find two entries in a database table with different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a membership mySQL database. One of the tables is for membership history and records each time a member renews. There is a unique auto-increment field, one for the member's login name (which is the constant for each member) and one for expiry date.

I'm looking for a way to search for all members who, for instance, expired in Nov 2014 and then renewed in Jan 2015 (their new expiry date would be Jan 2016). The data for each one would be in two separate rows in the table.

So I'm looking to find the login_name where expiry = Nov 14 and also find the same login name if there's another entry of expiry = Jan 16 then display the result as a list.

I've been working along these lines but I'm not there yet...

```
SELECT * FROM `membership_history` 
WHERE `login_name` IN (
    SELECT `login_name` 
    FROM `membership_history` 
    WHERE `membership_enddate` BETWEEN '2014-11-01' AND '2014-11-30' 
    OR `membership_enddate` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' 
    GROUP BY `login_name` HAVING count(`login_name`) > 1 
) 
ORDER BY `login_name`
```

Any tips or help would be appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd be inclined to write this as a `join` rather than `in`.  Then, you can eliminate the `where` clause, unless needed for performance reasons (it filters the data but is not needed to get the same results):

```
SELECT mh.*
FROM `membership_history` mh JOIN
     (select login_name
      from membership_history mh2
      group by login_name
      having sum(membership_enddate BETWEEN '2014-11-01' AND '2014-11-30') > 0 and
             sum(membership_enddate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31') > 0
    ) ml
    on mh.login_name = ml.login_name;
```